# How to convert date to dd/mm/yy in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am working with Amazon vendor central and downloading order data in csv format.

The date formats are as follows;

Jan 3, 2022 8:00:00 PM GMT

Please can anyone help me with a formula to convert to dd/mm/yy format?

Thanks
Laura

Comment: Show us what you have tried, please. Take a look at [ask].

Comment: You could use `SEARCH()` to split string, then process each field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MID()` and `FIND()` to pull out the data to enter into a `DATE(year, month, day)` or `DATEVALUE()` formula then use `TEXT(date, "DD/MM/YY")` to format it.

> The [DATEVALUE Function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-datevalue-function) can parse text as a date; but it seems it needs to be formatted "3 Jan 2022" as opposed to "Jan 3, 2022"

I have used an array rather than `MID()` to pull out the details and the formula for that is:

```
=LET(date, E3,
values, FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(date, " ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),
TEXT(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(values, 2), ",", " ") & INDEX(values, 1) & " " & INDEX(values, 3)), "DD/MM/YY")
)
```